# File creation task automation with python in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, shell, command-prompt

I am trying to build a task automation script using python and for that, I am following a tutorial from youtube.

> .my_commands.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function create() {
    python create.py
    echo $1
}
```

> create.py

```
print('Hello World')
```

and then in command prompt, I run this command `create aditya` which is supposed to print this according to tutorial.

```
Hello World
aditya
```

but instead it gives some error like this.

```
'create' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

In the tutorial they were using `mac`  system and i want to know is this possible to do the same on windows? If not why ?

Comment: I don't think this would work at all on a Mac either. Some parts of the code must have been missing. You must run `my_commands.sh` and somehow call the `create()` function within that Bash script.

Comment: This is the link of the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Y8Ppin12r4&list=PL5tVJtjoxKzqacJbIGbFbNTu7h2v4tsaF&index=2

Comment: @adityakumar : The error message says that you do not have an executable program or function named `create`. Did you source `.my_commands.sh` before trying to use your function?

Comment: @user1934428 I don't about source a file. Does that mean making it executable like we do in linux system using command `chmod +x fileName` ?

Comment: Which `fileName` are you talking about? You have in your posting only one file (`.my_commands.sh`), and since this file defines a function you want to use, it must be sourced by the shell which is supposed to use this function, and since it is a file to be sourced, you don't need x-bit. You also wouldn't need the `#!` line, though it is a good idea to have in, so that text editors can recognize what kind of syntax highlighting has to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this to directly execute your script:

```
python3 create.py
```

Or in the terminal you can write

```
> source .my_commands.sh
```

After which you can execute the `create` command to get the output exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows native equivalent to a shellscript is a *.bat file, which has its own syntax (since powershell it is possible to use shellscript but it comes with some issues on its own).

You can run the python script directly from the command line

```
python create.py
```

Comment: While doing everything inside Python indeed sounds most reasonable for me too, the OP seemingly wants to try out the interaction between POSIX shell functions and Python and hence doesn't want to use BAT or Powershell anyway. You do have several implementations of shell languages available for Windows 10, so I think we should advise him in this direction.